# Clicking to reload an updated answer removes the code snippet buttons and removes syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, stack-snippets

If you are looking at an answer with a code snippet in it, and the answerer updates the answer, you see `An edit has been made (etc.)`. If you click that, the answer is refreshed, but the code snippet buttons (Run, Copy, and Expand) go missing.

The code snippet buttons are there again after reloading the entire page.

*Answer has been edited:*

> [image]

*After clicking to reload it:*

> [image]

Similarly, non-snippet code blocks do not receive syntax highlighting after an edit, as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392257), which refers to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388534/3648282) as a related or root cause.

(Browser: Chrome v77 - OS: Windows 10 Pro x64)

Comment: The same issue has been reported on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388534/snippets-arent-working-when-refreshing-an-edit).

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem**

In [full.en.js](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/full.en.js), the function that adds syntax highlighting and snippet controls to posts (which is called `styleCode`, located on `window`) does not get called after an edit finishes. So, when the post is refreshed, the post body HTML gets replaced, but the snippet buttons are not re-created, and non-snippet code blocks do not receive syntax highlighting either.

**The Solution**

Stack Exchange can fix this by editing `realtime-se.js` so that the `postEdit` function calls `styleCode` after calling `reloadPosts`: Change

```
reloadPosts([post.id]);
```

to

```
reloadPosts([post.id]).then(styleCode);
```

(or do something else that eventually calls `styleCode`)

In the meantime, if you find it annoying, us users can fix it with [this userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Style-Code-After-Edit-Refresh) that manually calls `styleCode` when a post is refreshed.