# Styling not applies to code on edit after clicking "this post has been edited" message

Tags: bug, design, edits, live-refresh

When I was checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262193/3528424), I saw an alert about an Edit made to the post. I clicked that to see the edit and found the styling for code was not applied after edit. Ref below image [image: Ref 1] so I refreshed the page and found the styling is again applied to the code. Ref below image [image: Ref 2] I believe it's kind of bug so added a question over here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clicking to reload an updated answer removes the code snippet buttons and removes syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334625/clicking-to-reload-an-updated-answer-removes-the-code-snippet-buttons-and-remove)